# Where to reset sources list for apt-get on Mint 16?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt-get, aptitude

I'm trying to fix my `apt-get`, as it has been 404ing on `sudo apt-get update` for a while. However, nothing I do seems to fix these numerous 404s.

It appears that there are many different places to change the sources. These are:

1. Software Sources application (there are also a number of tabs on here - not sure which ones are useful).
2. /etc/apt/sources.list - editing this manually has given me no luck, despite copying a number of different sources.list I found online.
3. /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list - I think this is tied to the Software Sources app, so I didn't want to edit it manually.

I'm scared to manually remove every 404 that shows up when I run `apt-get update` because it would mean removing dozens of sources - could I be removing an important source?

So where/how do I get a "fresh" `apt-get`? Do I edit any of the above to some magical configuration that I have yet to see? Do I run some other command which will put `apt-get` back to factory settings? I don't care for any repository in particular, I just want it to act like it did when I first got Mint!

OS: Mint 16 (Cinnamon 2.0.14) 64 bit.

Comment: Did you fix all your proxy settings correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by "fix correctly"? As far as I know all my proxy settings are unchanged since install.

Comment: Because it was my problem. I used a public wifi connection and then automatically my proxy settings were changed, then I couldn't update or install any thing.